# JS Form based Basic Auth still displays browser credentials window?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, basic-authentication

I'm attempting to login with Basic Authentication via a standard web form and js.

The current code seems to authenticate correctly (RE: users trigger the Authenticated alert, and nonusers fail) but the redirect to the secured resource gets the browsers Basic Auth login prompt?

Is there something I'm missing here that will allow the initial authentication via JS to stick so the redirect can bypass the default login prompt?

-Login page is at the root of the same domain.
-The secure page is one dir deeper.

```
    var username = $("input#username").val();
    var password = $("input#password").val();
    var secureURL = "https://example.com/secure/"

    $.ajax
        ({
        type: "GET",
        url: secureURL,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        }
        })
        .done(function(){
            alert('Authenticated!')
            window.location.href = secureURL;
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('Error!')
        });
    });
```

**Edit:**
I think I got it.  This is the ajax request body that seems to work as expected.

```
$.ajax(
    {
      'password' : password,
      'username' : username,
      'url'      : secureURL,
      'type'     : 'GET',
      'success'  : function(){ window.location = secureURL; },
      'error'    : function(){ alert('Bad Login Details');},
    }
  );

  return false;
```

Comment: What does the GET return? Are you storing that they are authenticated at any point?

Comment: @VincentNguyen if I dump the get request into a variable it looks like I'm getting an jqxhr object back.

Comment: You should return your response in the `done` callback. Give it a parameter and see what you get back there. I don't know what kind of response you're getting but usually when authenticating it should be a `POST`, send login to server, server authenticates login, it sends back some sort of success and we store that in a `isAuthenticated` state

Comment: @VincentNguyen - I get the contents of the default HTML document in the secure folder.

Comment: Why are you doing that? Does your application have a backend?

Comment: The basic authentication is performed through IIS via Active Directory.   The application in the secure folder was written by another company to authenticate via HTTP basic. I'm trying to clean up the UX w/o having to dig into that app code.

Comment: It seems like you have to somehow send the authorization headers on every request (even after redirect). I found a way to do this is to include it in the URL `https://username:password@example.com/admin/...` but I believe this method is deprecated now, also it does not appear to be secure. I think the request is supposed to store a cookie for you but it clearly isn't working and i'm not sure why.